# Remove frame around legend in Python Object-Oriented plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to remove the frame around the legend box. I found few ways. However, none implement them with "axis method".

The code shown below gets the result but I wish to know a cleaner, more elegant way, perhaps like `ax.legend.draw_frame(False)` or something similar. Any ideas if such a way exists without using pylab?

SOLUTION: Make use of `ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc=3, frameon=False)` as suggested by [Evert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707650/evert)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import legend

x = np.linspace(1,10, 100)
y = x**3

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x,y, 'bo', label='Blah!')
lg = legend(numpoints = 1, loc=2)
lg.get_frame().set_alpha(0)
#ax.legend(numpoints = 1, loc=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: [`legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend) seems to have a keyword argument `frameon`; have you tried that (`ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc=2, frameon=False)`?

Comment: Hah, that does it. Where do you find/learn more about legend(). Matplotlib 1.4.0 had nothing about this. Thanks!

Comment: Searching for "matplotlib axis legend" will lead you directly (depending on your search engine) to the matplotlib documentation on the legend api.

Comment: @Evert Why don't you answer the question with your solution?

Comment: @Rohit please mark it as solved :)

Comment: @AmebaSpugnosa. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @Evert: Please Copy-Paste your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: @AmebaSpugnosa: I am in this situation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237547/how-to-mark-question-as-answered-solved-if-my-question-does-not-have-any-answe

Comment: Luckily, anyone can answer this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Evert does not wish to answer I will do so in order to mark it as solved. But please give him/her points.

Make use of `ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc=3, frameon=False)` as suggested by Evert